# Deleting websites in odoo

Tags: odoo

I am working in Odoo and I am trying to create a main website and multiple sub-websites. but I made the mistake of making too many websites and now I can not delete them. whenever I try to delete them it says this error: "The operation cannot be completed: another model requires the record being deleted. if possible, archive it instead.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete a website you need to also delete all the records the heavily depends on them like Menus, Pages...
Or you could write code to do the cascade deletion of everything in order to don't do it manually